# Subview UITableView in Xcode 5 without NavigationBar gap

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5

I am trying to add a UITableView (TV) as a subview in one of my xibs, and this TV include a SearchBar at the top. After I have setup my xib so it looks correct I try running the simulator, however the TV seems to be leaving a gap at the top to allow for the UINavigationBar (see screenshots below):

[image: XIB Screenshot]

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

Can anyone advise me on how to overcome this issue, I am running in to a lot of issues in Xcode 5 which I did not have before when setting up nibs.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard  and drag a tableview inside an UIView embedded inside a Navigation controller Xcode automatically considers the space for the navigation bar. 
if not add constraints. for a tableview you need 4 constraints:

- Leading
- Trailing
- Top space
- Bottom space

to add constraints select the tableview and go to *editor->pin* and select them

Comment: Hi, I've added the constraints but it still has the same issue. It's not the actual TV itself that is being misaligned, it seems to be it's content. So the blue colour is the BG of the TV, and as you can see all the content (SearchBar & TableCells) have been shifted downwards.

Comment: did you add constraint also for Tablecells and search bar?

Comment: It won't let me pin the UISearchBar, that's why I'm getting confused. It just seems to be automatically setup which would be great if it worked like it used too :)